# mysql- Database schema of messaging application with different group

Tags: php, mysql, database, schema

I know how to make a simple messaging schema for one to one user messaging ( all user come from same table) but my problem is that I have multiple Table with different type of users which have their primary keys now when a user from one table want to send a message to a user from another table then what should be schema for this application,
Let I have these three tables with different type of users-

```
TableA- id | Name |...
TableB- id | Name | ...
TableC- id | Name | ...
```

Now a user from TableA want to send a message to a user from TableB or TableC then what should be database schema for messaging app (all three tables can have different user with same primary key i.e id)

Comment: Why are your users in different tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storing the same types of data with slightly differing properties is antithetical to databases.  You can make it work by pointing to `Table.ID` within your application, but it's not pretty and not best practice.

What you're looking for is a single **users** table with one or more flags or references (more columns/fields in the table) indicating what details are different for each user.  If you need multiple user groups, you should simply have **groups** table.

eg.:

```
# users table
CREATE TABLE users (
  user_id INT,
  user_name VARCHAR(32),
  group_id INT,
  talk_outside_group BOOL
);

# groups table
CREATE TABLE user_groups (
  group_id INT,
  group_name VARCHAR(32),
);

INSERT INTO user_groups SET group_id = 1, group_name = 'PHBs';
INSERT INTO user_groups SET group_id = 2, group_name = 'HR';

INSERT INTO users SET user_id = 1, group_id = 1, user_name = 'Alice';
INSERT INTO users SET user_id = 2, group_id = 1, user_name = 'Bob';
INSERT INTO users SET user_id = 3, group_id = 2, user_name = 'Carol';
INSERT INTO users SET user_id = 4, group_id = 2, user_name = 'Dave';
```

In this example, Alice and Bob are PHBs and can barely work their keyboards.

Carol and Dave are HR drones and have boring conversations ;)

When and whether users of separate groups can talk to each other could be indicated by a flag in either table (depending on how granular you need the privilege control... in this example, the `talk_outside_group` field) and should be handled in the application layer.

Answer (score 0):

Your users shouldn't be in different tables.

If you want some users to have privileges then do a table "privileges" and link it to "users" with a table "user_privilege" which would contain "id_user" and "id_privilege".

If you really want to do what you are doing, then you'll have to add a field "table_name" in the message table to be able to know from where the user is coming.